# "Database does not exist" - Set path to SQLITE database for API route in Laravel

Tags: laravel, sqlite, laravel-5

In my Laravel (5.4) project I want to use sqlite. But when trying to access it I get an "Database does not exist" error.

In my .env file I use

```
DB_CONNECTION=sqlite
DB_DATABASE=database/easyresults.sqlite
```

I used `touch database/easyresults.sqlite` to create the db and successfully ran the migrations using `php artisan migrate`. But when accessing it using a XMLHTTPRequest, I get the error above.

After changing the path in the .env file to

```
DB_DATABASE=../database/easyresults.sqlite
```

I can acces it again, however any command line call doesn't work then.

What am I missing? Does it not work using the .env file? Do I have to use database_path('easyresults.sqlite') and put it directly into config/database.php?

Thanks a lot for your support.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to have the database filename in your .env you can do `database_path(env('DB_DATABASE', 'dbfilename'));` in your config/database.php

then in your .env you would have
`DB_DATABASE=easyresults.sqlite`

Comment: Cool, this is what I think I'll use: `'database' => database_path(env('DB_DATABASE', 'database') . '.sqlite')`